# Solve iteratively dataframe in R

Tags: r

i am trying to build a dataframe (df2) based on the following relationship: df1[i,j] = df2[i,j]^2. For doing this, i need to solve a system of non-linear equations:

```
 library(nleqslv)
 df1 = data.frame(a = c(9,9), b = c(9,9))
 df2 = df1

for(i in colnames(df1)){
  f = function(x) {df1[i] - x^2}                       
  xstart = c(df2[i])
  df2[i] = nleqslv(xstart, f)[[1]]
}
```

The expected result is:

```
  a b
1 3 3
2 3 3
```

But i get the following error message:

```
Error in nleqslv(xstart, f) : 
  Argument 'x' cannot be converted to numeric!
```

not sure what causes the problem. Could you give me some advice please?

Comment: Take a look at the answer I posted - let me know if you have any question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unclear as to why you need such a complex solution for such a simple operation (`df2 <- sqrt(df1)` would produce your example solution). But if you want to know what's producing that error, it comes down to how R indexes lists.

`df1[1]` returns a *list*, whereas `df1[[1]]` (double brackets) returns the *vector*. The nleqslv function expects vectors. So all we have to do is modify your existing code to use double brackets instead of singles:

```
library(nleqslv)
df1 = data.frame(a = c(9,9), b = c(9,9))
df2 = df1

for(i in colnames(df1)){
  f = function(x) {df1[[i]] - x^2}                       
  xstart = c(df2[[i]])
  df2[i] = nleqslv(xstart, f)[[1]]
}
```

Comment: Also, you don't need `c()` in `c(df2[[i]])`.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I should have mentioned that it was just a simplified example. The function i use is more complex and i do not know how to rearrange "df2" on the left side.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know what you are trying to accomplish, but I think the function you defined has to be fixed. You can do it in the following manner, although the answer is not correct.

```
f <- function(x) x - x^2
df1 = data.frame(a = c(9,9), b = c(9,9))
sapply(df1, function(y) nleqslv(y, f)[[1]])
```

---

You should instead use `sqrt()` since it is vectorized.

```
sqrt(df1)
#   a b
# 1 3 3
# 2 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

First creating the data:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(9,9), b=c(9,9))
df1 <- df2
```

Now on solving it iteratively, here's the R code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df1)){
    df2[i, j] <- sqrt(df1[i,j])
  }
}
df2
```

This will return:

```
<dbl>
a   b
3   3           
3   3
```

You could have used a vectorized solution (`df2 <- sqrt(df1)`) to achieve the above as well, but the loop function above will work for you if you need to solve for it iteratively using a traditional loop.